# Converting int64_t to string in C

Tags: c, postgresql, postgresql-12

I am working with C programming language and using Postgres database to insert records. One of the columns of the table in the database is of type `timestamp`. The data I am getting in the C program is of type `int64_t` and I need to pass this value as a parameter in the `INSERT` statement like shown below. In order to do that, I tried to convert the `int64_t` value to a string using `sprintf()`.

```
 char str[21];
 sprintf(str, "%" PRId64 "\n", someTimeReceived inTheProgram);  
 const char * const paramValues[1] = { str };

 PGresult *res =     res = PQexecParams(
            conn,
            "INSERT INTO dummy VALUES(1,to_timestamp($1)::timestamp)",

            1,            /* one parameter */
            NULL,
            paramValues,
            NULL,        /* parameter lengths are not required for strings */
            NULL,        /* all parameters are in text format */
            0            /* result shall be in text format */
        );
```

But on using `sprintf()`, some garbage value are being inserted at the end of string. For example if the received `int64_t` value is `132408394771256230` then `sprintf()` is converting it to `132408394771256230\n\0\003`. Because of the extra garbage values appended at the end of string, the program fails to insert the given value and then terminates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if the received int64_t value is `132408394771256230` then `sprintf()` is converting it to `132408394771256230\n\0\003`

no, `sprintf` only writes `132408394771256230\n\0` into *str* and let the rest of the array unchanged, the character of code 3 was present before the call of `sprintf` (the array is not initialized) but of course it   can be anything else.

> Because of the extra garbage values appended at the end of string, the program fails to insert the given value and then terminates.

no again, *PQexecParams* manages *params* as an array of strings (one string in your case) following the convention a string is ended by a null character, *PQexecParams* does not read/care about what there is after the null character, and does know even about the 'envelop' of your string (an array of 21 characters in your case).

Your problem probably comes because of the undesirable newline in your string, producing the command to be the string

```
INSERT INTO dummy VALUES(1,to_timestamp(132408394771256230\n)::timestamp)
```

just remove `\n` in the format of your `sprintf`.

---

Supposing it is needed to have the newline your array must be sized 22 rather than 21 to manage negative value without an undefined behavior writing out of the array.

---

> ...some garbage value

you certainly see the null character and the byte after because you use a debugger and that debugger knows *str* is sized 21 and when you ask to see the value of *str* the debugger consider *str* as an array of characters rather than a string. If you ask your debugger to show `(char*) str` it will consider *str* as a string and will not show the null character nor the character after.

---

**[edit]**

The function request the date-time as a string *yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss* rather than your big number being an *ua_datetime*

To convert an *ua_datetime* to a the expected string use (see [documentation](https://documentation.unified-automation.com/uasdkhp/1.2.1/html/group__ua__base__datetime.html#ga894ad963e74cd207f735e559b2a54b39)) :

```
nt ua_datetime_snprintf (char * dst, size_t size, const ua_datetime * dt)
```

the result is a string *YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.nnnZ* so after just replace the last dot by a null character and 'T' by a space (supposing a 'T' is really produced, try and adapt)

An other way is to use :

```
time_t ua_datetime_to_time_t(const ua_datetime * dt)
```

then to make your string with standard function from the *time_t*

Anyway you have to understand you loose a lot of precision, *ua_datetime* are in 100 nanosecond while *postgress timestamp are in second only

Comment: I removed `\n` but still no luck in inserting the record in the database and the program is getting terminated.

Comment: @ABeginner do you come back from *PQexecParams* ? if yes what it returns ? Can you run your program using *valgrind* (compile with debug first) ? are you sure about *timestamp* representation as a big number rather than *yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss* for instance ?

Comment: Do you mean what status code it returns? If so, then it returns 7.

Comment: @ABeginner and what 7 means ? If *PQexecParams* returns where do you have your crash ? Again can you use *valgrind* ?

Comment: It stands for `PGRES_FATAL_ERROR` which implies that the query execution has failed.

Comment: ok, so can you try with a typestamp having the form *yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss* in the string whatever the values just to try ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219094/discussion-between-a-beginner-and-bruno).